# how to get random rows sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I've a big database ,about 3500 rows .I tried to use order by rand() and it's not working . as I heard , it's bad idea to using order by rand() .

How can I get random rows from database in sqlite ?

thanks you

Comment: Mow many rows at a time?

Comment: http://blog.rodolfocarvalho.net/2012/05/how-to-select-random-rows-from-sqlite.html

Answer (score 1):

It should work for random ordered row

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY rand();
```

For specific number of rows

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM();
```

For more info see  [Selecting a Random Row from an SQLite Table](http://www.bernzilla.com/2008/05/13/selecting-a-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3500;
```